# LibGDX render not called after resize

Tags: java, android, libgdx, render

I'm making a simple 2D game in LibGDX. This is my first project with it.

On my phone everything works fine, nothing bad (6.0.1), but on other phones (no matter what version) it doesn't work. It's clear that the render method doesn't work, but I don't know why. I've tried to add `super.render();` but it made it red, so it's not working or I've made some mistake.

This is a menu screen, what comes first. It works fine, than I play and die, than I call it again and it crashes.

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

private DualisAutosapp game;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
...
  public MenuScreen(DualisAutosapp game)
    {
    super();
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Started");


    this.game = game;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Camera");

    logoTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.png"));
    logoTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    logo = new Sprite(logoTexture);
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Background");

    startTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("start.png"));
    startTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    start = new Sprite(startTexture);
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Start");

    carChooseTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(prefs.getString("playercar", "player/mazda2.png")));
    carChooseTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    carChoose = new Sprite(carChooseTexture);
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Car");

    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font/joystix_monospace.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("font/joystix_monospace.png"), false);


    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","batch");

    calculateSpriteLocation(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","calculate");
    }

   @Override
   public void show() {

   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height) {
       camera = new OrthographicCamera();
       camera.setToOrtho(false,Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

       calculateSpriteLocation(width,height);
   }

   @Override
   public void render (float delta) {
       Gdx.app.log("Menu","render");
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    ...
   }
   @Override
    public void resume() {
    Gdx.app.log("Menu","Rizjúm");
    carChooseTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(prefs.getString("playercar", "player/mazda2.png")));
    carChooseTexture.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
    carChoose = new Sprite(carChooseTexture);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    private void calculateSpriteLocation(int width, int height)
    {
        logo.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        logo.setPosition(width/2-logo.getWidth()/2, height/2-logo.getHeight()/2);

        start.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/3.6f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6.4f);
        start.setPosition(width/2-start.getWidth()/2, height/2-start.getHeight()/2);

        carChoose.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/3.6f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/6.4f);
        carChoose.setPosition(width/2-carChoose.getWidth()/2, height/10-carChoose.getHeight()/2);
    }
}
```

Everything is ok until the log of the render where it crashes.

**EDIT**

Game Class

```
public class DualisAutosapp extends Game {

  @Override
  public void create () {
      showMenuScreen();
  }

  public void switchScreen(Screen newScreen){
      Screen previousScreen = getScreen();
      setScreen( newScreen );

      if (previousScreen != null)
      {
          previousScreen.dispose();
      }
  }

  public void showMenuScreen()
  {
      switchScreen(new MenuScreen(this));
  }

  public void showGameScreen()
  {
      switchScreen(new GameScreen(this));
  }

  public void showCarChangeScreen() {
      switchScreen( new CarChange(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show your `Game` class ? and why are you creating camera in `resize` method.

Comment: Game class was added up.

It was in a teaching video serial. It's from there.

Comment: Add crash log ?

Comment: 01-07 23:31:26.492 26218-26245/hu.qnszt.dualisautosapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x57348008 (code=1), thread 26245 (Thread-1698)

Comment: only a single line of error ?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: Could you just create your camera in Show and clear resize and try it out ?

Comment: 01-08 00:52:47.652 26782-26809/hu.qnszt.dualisautosapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x5734c008 (code=1), thread 26809 (Thread-1731)

Comment: @Szabbi97 code is not enough to find your bug, so please show some more code,

Comment: Have you override `dispose()` method of any of your `Screen` class

Comment: Edited.

No I don't override dispose.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'll recommend you to follow [Life cycle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/The-life-cycle) method of `Game`/`Screen` of Libgdx API. If you not override lifecycle method of Game then it call `Screen` corresponding method.

You're initialize your objects whenever you want but it's not a good way. It's better to initialize all your screen object inside `show` method of `Screen` Interface.

Create object's of all screens inside Game class at once and only use that object in `setScreen(screen)` method.

```
@Override
public void show() {
   ..//create objects
}
```

Use `dispose()` method and destroy objects that you created in `show()`. 
Method `resize()` can be used to update viewport of camera with device size. 
Use `pause()` and `resume()` according to your requirement like music pause but not for object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Well,i think you should not pass Game class to screen constructors every time, and you could try something like this for screen management.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;

public enum MyScreens {

    GAME_SCREEN {
        public Screen getScreenInstance() {
            return new GameScreen();
        }
    },
    MAIN_MENU {
        public Screen getScreenInstance() {
            return new MainMenu();
        }
    },
    SPLASH_SCREEN {
        public Screen getScreenInstance() {
            return new SplashScreen();
        }
    };
    public abstract Screen getScreenInstance();

}



import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.IntMap;

public class ScreenManager {

    private static ScreenManager instance;
    private Game game;
    private IntMap<Screen> screens;

    private ScreenManager() {
        screens = new IntMap<Screen>();
    }

    public static ScreenManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ScreenManager();
        }
        return instance;

    }

    public void initialize(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void show(MyScreens screen) {

        if (game == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (!screens.containsKey(screen.ordinal())) {
            screens.put(screen.ordinal(), screen.getScreenInstance());
        }
        game.setScreen(screens.get(screen.ordinal()));
    }

    public void dispose(MyScreens screen) {
        if (!screens.containsKey(screen.ordinal())) {
            return;
        }
        screens.remove(screen.ordinal()).dispose();
    }

    public void dispose() {
        for (Screen screen : screens.values()) {
            screen.dispose();
        }
        screens.clear();
        instance = null;
    }

}
```